# Group by where NULL entries exist

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to join two tables (purchases and purchase attributes), and then group based on the join, however NULL values are generated during the join as not every entry in table A has a corresponding 'attributes' in table B - this then kills my 'group by'.

My actual implementation is more complicated than this but here is a trimmed concept of what I am trying to achieve:

I have the following Tables:

purchases:

```
|purchase_id | products_id |   qty    |
|      1     |   10        |   100    |
|      2     |   11        |   100    |
|      3     |   10        |   300    |
|      4     |   12        |    50    |
```

purchase_attributes:

```
|purchase_attributes_id | purchase_id | options_id |
|         1             |      1      |     5      |
|         2             |      3      |     5      |
|         3             |      4      |     5      |
```

Now, my goal is to calculate the total qty of a particular product, grouping by options_id.
So, I have the following sql:

```
select products_id, options_id, SUM(qty) 
from purchases
left join purchase_attributes using(purchase_id)
group by products_id, options_id
```

Which works for all cases where the purchase_id is listed in the purchase_attributes table, however for the case of purchase_id 2, which does not appear in purchase_attributes, it does not display in my result set.

Example result set:

```
| products_id  | options_id  |  SUM(qty)  |
|     10       |     5       |    400     |
|     12       |     5       |     50     |
```

However I would like to receive the following result set:

```
| products_id  | options_id  |  SUM(qty)  |
|     10       |     5       |    400     |
|     11       |     NULL    |    100     |
|     12       |     5       |     50     |
```

I have tried a few things, including Coalesce inside the group by and Union(ing) two select statements together, however I cannot seem to get the correct results.

Any ideas? thanks in advance.

Comment: might `GROUP BY isnull(products_id, -1)` work?

Comment: If you change your left join using to left join purchase_attributes on purchases.purchase_id = purchase_attributes.purchase_id, you may see different results. This is because the new join syntax has some caveats with how comparisons with nulls are formed. If you remove the sum column, and just do the join, do you see the null entries for purchase_id = 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **does** produce exactly your desired results.

```
SELECT products_id,options_id,SUM(qty)
FROM   (SELECT 1 AS purchase_id,10 AS products_id,100 AS qty
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2,11,100
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3,10,300
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 4,12,50) purchases
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 AS purchase_attributes_id,1 AS purchase_id,5 AS
                         options_id
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT 2,3,5
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT 3,4,5) purchase_attributes USING(purchase_id)
GROUP  BY products_id,options_id
```

Please provide an example that actually demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks for your reply - I apologize I had not tested my 'stripped' down case I simply assumed that it would produce the same problem. However, I have now found that the actual issue with my code is that I am also joining to an options table which has multiple options in multiple languages, becuase I had done 'where options.languages_id = '1', I was excluding all of the cases where that field was NULL (produced when unable to complete join).
Thanks for your help, you aided to point me in the right direction by proving the problem did not lie where I believed it did.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I haven't been able to try this code, just whipped it up right now.. so please just test it first..

```
    SELECT p.products_id, pa.options_id
        , SUM(qty) AS sum_qty
    FROM purchases AS p
    LEFT JOIN purchase_attributes AS pa 
    ON p.purchase_id = pa.purchase_id
    GROUP BY p.products_id, pa.options_id
```

Let me know if it doesn't work and what results you get..

Answer (score 0):

Apologies readers, this was my mistake. The answer I wrote in the question (which I believed to be faulty), actually worked fine - it was some other code in my actual, more complex statement that was causing this to fail.

I apologize for wasting anyones time with this.